# Javalin Migration from 3 to 4

Tags: kotlin, compression, gzip, javalin

We are migrating the Javalin from 3 to 4 in our current kotlin project. the dynamicGzip has been deprecated and replaced with compression strategy.
The pom.xml part will look like below.

```
<properties>      
  <javalin.version>4.1.1</javalin.version>
  <jackson.version>2.13.0</jackson.version>
</properties>
```

The code part of kotlin is as follows

```
import io.javalin.Javalin
import io.javalin.apibuilder.ApiBuilder.*
import io.javalin.http.BadRequestResponse
import io.javalin.http.NotFoundResponse
import io.javalin.http.staticfiles.Location
import io.javalin.plugin.json.JavalinJackson
import io.javalin.core.compression.*

val app = Javalin.create { config ->
        config.defaultContentType = "application/json"
        config.enableWebjars()
        config.addStaticFiles("", Location.CLASSPATH)
        config.enableCorsForAllgOrigins()
        //it.dynamicGzip = true // deprecated method which was used in 3.12.0
        config.compressionStrategy(Gzip(6))
    }
```

We are using the migrating document from this link
https://javalin.io/migration-guide-javalin-3-to-4

When we try to build the project in intelij Idea with this change, ended with the below error.

```
 D:\app\src\main\kotlin\app\app.kt:78:40
 Kotlin: Unresolved reference: Gzip
```

What is that we are missing here?

Also it will be helpfull if config.addStaticFiles syntax is also added wrt javalin 4

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation, because I am using Java not Kotlin. This works for me:  `import io.javalin.core.compression.*` and `config.compressionStrategy(new Brotli(6), new Gzip(6));`. In other words, I need both Brotli and Gzip. This is using Javalin 4.1.1.

Comment: Also this is my static file set-up: `config.addStaticFiles("/public", Location.CLASSPATH);`

Comment: Thanks @andrewJames, it worked, where as next error I got is Kotlin: Unresolved reference: enableCorsForAllgOrigins

Comment: @andrewJames I have edited the question with javalin classes which have been used, is there another one for ```enableCorsForAllgOrigins``` ?

Comment: That is a typo: `enableCorsForAllgOrigins` should be `enableCorsForAllOrigins`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Compression**

The `compressionStrategy` method of the `JavalinConfig` class takes two parameters:

```
void compressionStrategy(Brotli brotli, Gzip gzip)
```

See the JavaDoc [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.javalin/javalin/latest/io/javalin/core/JavalinConfig.html).

The related classes are found in Javalin here:

```
import io.javalin.core.compression.Brotli;
import io.javalin.core.compression.Gzip;
```

So, you can do something like this in your set-up (my example is Java not Kotlin):

```
// my Java example:
config.compressionStrategy(new Brotli(6), new Gzip(6));
```

**Static Files**

You can use something like this (again, a Java example not Kotlin):

```
// my Java example:
config.addStaticFiles("/public", Location.CLASSPATH);
```

In this case, because I want my files to be on the runtime classpath, I have also created a `public` directory in my application's `resources` directory. Your specific implementation may differ.

You can also use `Location.EXTERNAL` if you prefer, to place the files somewhere else in your filesystem (outside the application).

---

Note also there is a small typo in `config.enableCorsForAllgOrigins()`. It should be:

```
config.enableCorsForAllOrigins()
```